# How to insert random values in array

Tags: ruby

I tried to create a 10 X 10 array that is randomly filled with either `"A"` or `"D"`. I found the following code.

```
Array.new(10){Array.new(10) { rand >0.5 ? "A" : "D"}}
```

I cannot understand the code. Could someone explain this code?

Comment: What specifically do you not understand?

Comment: You could replace the inner block with `["A", "D"].sample`, which is much more legible.

Comment: Each `Array.new(10)` passes an index to its block (`0, 1,.., 9`) so you could write this `a = Array.new(10) { |i| Array.new(10) { |j| rand >0.5 ? "A" : "D" } }`.  When the block variables (here `i` and `j`) are not used in the block calculations, they can be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part in the {} is called a **codeblock**

So you are applying this pattern twice

```
Array.new(10){codeblock}
```

It's saying - create an array of ten items where each item is the result from the codeblock

The inner codeblock:

```
{rand >0.5 ? "A" : "D"}
```

is called the [**ternary operator**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Ruby). It chooses a new random number each time and compares it to `0.5`. If the number is greater than `0.5` then "A" will be the result of the codeblock. Otherwise it will be "D"

Since `rand` returns a uniform distribution of numbers between 0 and 1, there is a 50% chance of an item being "A" and 50% chance of it being a "D"

Comment: rand is where i got struck.. and creating an array inside the block.. now i can understand.. thankyou for ur explanation John

Answer (score 0):

[John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34348759/794242) has explained the particular code snippet you shared.

There are many ways to accomplish what you are trying to do.  Here are couple more ways to this:

```
Array.new(10).fill (["A","D"] * 5).to_a.shuffle!
Array.new(10).fill ["A","D"].cycle(5).to_a.sample(10)
```